# How to send an image from a database via mail

Tags: android, email, attachment

I am getting an image inforamtion as string from a database and by using that string I create a bitmap image.

Now my question is how am I sending this image and matter also via mail. This image is not stored on the sdcard or anywhere else.

Answer (score 1):

1. Store that bitmap on your filesystem
2. Then use following code to attach that file to your email:

   ```
   File F = new File("/path/to/your/file.png");
   Uri U = Uri.fromFile(F);
   Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
   i.setType("image/png");
   i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, U);
   startActivity(Intent.createChooser(i,"Email:"));
   ```